# Android Studio - ListView and Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, listview

So basically I have a study assignment and it consists of creating an android app that works with two activities. When you click on the main activity, you are taken to the second activity, a map. Now the main activity is a list view, which has by default the item "Add a new location". When you click it, the map appears. However, my app is supposed to add items to the list view by long clicking the map. For example, if I long click the map, a marker should appear in that location, and then the name of that location should then appear on the main activity list view. I've tried several different methods, but I can;t make my app to add extra items to the list. My app doesn;t crash or anything, but it just won;t add items to the list view, and I WANT to add items.

Here is the code:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static ArrayList<String> places;
static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    places = new ArrayList<>();
    places.add("Enter a memorable location... ");
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, places);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Maps Activty:

```
 public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Memorable Places");
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            String address ="";
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude, 1);
                if(addressList!=null && addressList.size() > 0){
                    address = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    MainActivity.places.add(address);
                    MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(point)
                    .title(address)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Double lon = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng current = new LatLng(lat, lon);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 15));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, this);
}
```

Comment: Create a database to store the list of places to show in your listview. Then when you add a place by longclicking on your map, add that place in your DB. Then everytime your mainactivity opens, read the data from your DB and show in your listview. This will take a small amount of time, unless you have thousands of places in your DB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onResume()` method in your MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (arrayAdapter != null) {
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Hope it hels you.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted the problem. However, it only works if I click the back button on the phone. If I click the back button on the title bar, nothing will show up. If I click the back button from the phone, it shows up! The problem lies in the title bar back button! Any suggestions?

Comment: @GuillermoHerrera Since your **main** concern was already solved with this, you should accept it as the correct answer. Your follow up is a separate issue.

Comment: @GuillermoHerrera Override the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method and write your logic in it like: `@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //Write your logic here
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }`